# How to kill several processes with different time of executing?

Tags: bash

I have simple bash script:

> ( sleep 5; echo 'A'; sleep 100 ) &
>
> ( sleep 7; echo 'B'; sleep 100 ) &

I want to kill this two process after second process print 'B' and of couse first process print 'A'.   ( May be not echo - may be other label after first sleep. ) How to do it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
( sleep 5; echo 'A'; sleep 100 ) &
export Last=$!
( sleep 7; echo 'B'; kill-9 $Last; sleep 100 ) &
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jobs -p | xargs kill
```

`jobs -p` prints the process IDs of all background jobs from this shell window.

`xargs` passes what it reads on `stdin` to the program you provide.

`kill` sends `SIGTERM` to each process ID you give it.

Note, though, that this will kill ALL background jobs started from this shell, not just the last two.

If you know you want to kill just the most recently started X jobs, use this:

```
jobs -p | tail -n [number of jobs] | xargs kill
```